# "The automatic tile updater is not enabled"

Tags: tiles, live-tiles

Just seen an alert on my WP7.5 start screen which I've not seen before and can't reproduce. So I can't get the wording exact. But it was something like "The automatic tile updater is not enabled on this device".

Was this from the phone or from an app? What did it mean?

By "alert" I mean the black alert which fills 1/3 of the top of the screen (as in the rough mockup below):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think this could have been the [Chronos Calendar app](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/store/app/chronos-calendar/18aae83d-c70c-4ac1-8bf6-c6e726e031df) which is on my start screen. About half an hour after seeing the error (not immediately, though ...) the Chronos tile stopped showing upcoming appointments and just showed a logo. Even after a restart.

In the Chronos settings I found the Live Tile `Activated` setting was unchecked. Switched it on again and got Chronos back to how it was before.

I assume the alert was from Chronos, perhaps encountering some kind of glitch.